# "sockjs-node/iframe.html 404 (Not Found)" with React and Alt

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux, wordpress-rest-api

As I've followed [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-react-apps-on-top-of-the-wordpress-rest-api-bcc632808025) to start my first project with ReactJS and the WordPress REST API, I've stumbled upon a problem with sockjs-node, that I'm not able to locate on Google.

I've reached the part **Dynamic Routes** in the tutorial and first got problems saying that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/info?t=1248291038`, but realised that the **webpack.dev.js** file had to change this:

`entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
]`

into this:

`entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/'
]`

The problem is, now all I'm getting when I run `npm start` is a console that looks like this:

[image: 404 errors with sockjs-node]

I seem to be able to get the reload to work on `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html` (still getting the error messages though), but not on `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

From here, I have no clue what to do. Any ideas? Much appreciated!